# How do I pull from remote git?

Tags: git

I'm a total git noob. I've been given the task of making some changes to a website but for some of those changes I have to access files on a git repository. The link I've been given is so:

/opt/git/repositories/*******_site.git

How do I use this link to connect to the repository?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't belong here IMO.... granted this isn't really Offtopic but do we really need to copy the git documentation?

Comment: @Daij-Djan If we voted to close every question where documentation exists somewhere that answers the OP's question - we'd have a very quiet site.

Comment: In cases where I can just google the exact thing that'd be good. I could also see this as a general computer question

Answer (score 1):

If the path you have been given is accessible to you, it would be just as simple as;

`git clone /opt/git/repositories/*******_site.git`

Then you can interact with it like any other Git repo. You may need to specify the **full** filepath though. For example;

`git clone D:/Projects/opt/git/repositories/*******_site.git`